# Remove square brackets and their contents using jQuery + regexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, wordpress

Using an example [I've found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/a9cvx/4/), I am trying to remove occurrences of text that are surrounded by these `[` `]` square brackets.

I have many occurrences of `[sample-text]` in my html and want to remove the whole thing, including the brackets.

I've tried this but it doesn't work -- nothing is being replaced:

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/^\[.*\]$/g,'');
$("body").html(replaced);
```

I am trying to match the start using `[` and the end with `]` and remove the inner content but I am getting nowhere.

Comment: You want to remove the ^ and $, as they aren't the beginning or ending of the total text or lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var replaced = $("body").html().replace(/\[.*\]/g,'');
$("body").html(replaced);
```